# Custom graph in scaladoc

Tags: dot, scaladoc

Is there any easy way how to add graph to my scaladoc documentation?

I have found only the possibility to generate class hierarchy graphs but I want to include my own graph.
The only way I have found is to create external image and include it into documentation but it is too complicated.

I'm looking for a way how to include graph description directly into scaladoc comments. Something like

```
/** My class description
  *
  * @digraph{
  *   new -> open
  *   open -> closed
  *   closed -> open
  * }
  */
```

The [dot language](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) is preferred for me but any other graph description language is also acceptable.